# Background threads in delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, threadpool

Is there any analog for Delphi that specify that some thread is background thread? As for .NET I can say `SomeThread.IsBackground = true;` and this thread will become background.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Delphi, every thread except the main thread is a background thread. That's why you can only update the GUI from the main thread.

Comment: In Windows there's nothing like a "background thread". You can specify a thread priority (SetThreadPriority) to have some thread pre-empted by more "critical" ones when needed (i.e. a thread that generates and print a report may have a lower priority than the main thread that handles user input). It looks .NET implementation took a simplified approach, and just "kills" "background" thread when a program exits (it works due to the GC), IMHO it's a dangerous approach, threads should exit cleanly when possibile. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If a program exits, threads should exit cleanly when it is absolutely necessary that they do so, eg. to ensure that files that the thread has open for writing are flushed.  If there is no explicit reason to enforce a clean exit, why bother?

Comment: Threads may be using synchronization objects and the like. IMHO it is better to ensure everything is released correctly, especially in a pure Windows application.

Comment: Threads may indeed be using synchronization objects and, if they are named objects used for inter-process communication, then it is possible that some special action may be required on app close.  If the synchro. is used for inter-thread comms within the app that is closing, we are back to 'why bother?'.  I agree that better to ensure everything is released correctly, and the best way to do this is to let the OS release everything after it has stopped all the process threads.  Explicitly terminating and destroying all threads on app close causes a load of hassle for no gain.

Comment: Read what MSDN says about ExitProcess() and threads: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658(v=vs.85).aspx. I do not know how the .NET framework implemented threads, but it could have much more control upon them than a Delphi application which uses a very thin layer above threads.

Also MSDN says: "Do not terminate a process unless its threads are in known states. If a thread is waiting on a kernel object, it will not be terminated until the wait has completed" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686722(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @ldsandon .net threads are heavily managed and not really subject to quite the same rules as native threads

Comment: @David: my point. You can't handle threads in Delphi like you would do in .NET. But this question as about Delphi threads, aka native threads. IMHO having threads terminating cleaning is a good practices, instead simply exiting the process and hope for best :)

Comment: @ldsandon Yes, for native threads one should always terminate and join each thread before going down.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan etc. 'for native threads one should always terminate and join each thread before going down' - why?  Unless there is some reason to terminate a thread, (flush file, close DB connection), why should I inflict all that extra work on myself when I could just let the OS do it?

Comment: @ldsandon - -Do not terminate a process unless its threads are in known states. If a thread is waiting on a kernel object, it will not be terminated until the wait has completed' - that would mean that the task manager could not stop most processes.  Also, ExitProcess()<>TerminateProcess().

Comment: @Martin Maybe so. Code I write can also exist in a DLL and in that situation you do need to clean up properly. Even in an exe you have to be sure that killing a thread really is benign.

Comment: @Martin: that MSDN pages is not about TerminateProces(). Paragraph "How Processes are Terminated" shows what could terminate a process. TerminateProcess() is just one of them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The .net documentation describes the [IsBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) property like this:

> A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread. Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating. Once all foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads are stopped and do not complete.

A Delphi process terminates when the main function in the .dpr file completes. This main function always runs in the context of the main process thread, that is the thread that is automatically created by the system when the process starts.

So, in Delphi there is no equivalent property. There is a single foreground thread, the main thread, and all other threads are background thread, using the .net terminology. A thread cannot, at runtime, change state from foreground to background, or vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

To verify that the current thread is the main VCL thread, check TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID = MainThreadID(*). The main VCL thread is supposed to stay the foreground thread, and is the only thread where the GUI should be updated, so the answer to your question is "no".

If you are using a recent version of Delphi you can however make use of TThread.CreateAnonymousThread and TThread.Synchronize in order to have anonymous methods executed in either a background thread or in the main VCL thread, respectively.

*) Please note that the CurrentThread class property was added only a few versions back. If you are using an old Delphi version, such as Borland Delphi 7, you can only perform this check from within the execute method of the thread (or from any method that is called by Execute etc).

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi, every thread except the main thread is a background thread. That's why you can only update the GUI from the main thread.